# How to see progress of snapshot restoration in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I have pretty big snapshot of Acumatica information ( ~2.5 Gb ). Last time when I tried to restore snapshot it took me two days and nights and didn't complete. How it's possible to speed up snapshot restoration and how to see the progress of restoration. Because for now progress of restoration has very low level of information. Few more details: I have windows server instance where I have permissions of system administrator

Comment: This is likely something you're aware, general database optimization recommendation would apply: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/12/optimizing-large-import.html

Comment: I do not have access to source database. Even if I had I'm not sure that I can do anything. It is hosted in cloud of Acumatica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure proper progress reporting would require modification to Acumatica internal classes. Being internal, those classes can't be modified.

It is possible to monitor the process to a certain extent using SQL Server Profiler:
[image]

I tested the following filter in SQL Server Profiler 'Trace Properties':

First remove Security Audit Logout:
[image]

Open column filters:
[image]

Filter ApplicationName = '.Net SqlClient Data Provider'
[image]

Filter TextData = 'insert bulk%'
[image]